# Frame for Search Bar will be different at run time

Tags: xcode, warnings

I have a problem to remove a warning. I added a search bar into my viewController, everything is working fine but i recieve this warning:

[image]

I updated all constraints + the position and it disappears but after reopening my project, the warning is still there. I tried every clue.
I need help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click the yellow warning indicator on the right side of the Category Table View Controller scene, you will be able to select an Xcode recommended fix for your warning (in this case you want to select the update frames option).

Comment: I know, after reopening my file, the warning ist still there. Changing frames has no effect.

Comment: I found some informations, that it's a bug in xcode?! Thanks anyway